# Changing Kubernetes cluster IP to internal IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a Kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud. I have done it a few months ago and configured the cluster to have external IP address limited with authorized networks.

[image]

I want to change the cluster IP to internal IP. Is this possible without re-creating the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#restrictions), you currently "**cannot** convert an existing, non-private cluster to a private cluster."

Having said that, you'll need to create a new private cluster from scratch, which will have both an external IP and an internal IP. However, you'll be able to disable access to the external IP or restrict access to it as per your needs. Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#access_to_the_cluster_endpoints) for the different settings available.